# How to get the method to return and print in main? Java

Tags: java, computer-science

I've written the whole program, but I still can't get the discount to apply to the second print.
Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create array
        
        Book[] bookArray = new Book[6];
        
        // use parameterized constructor to create books
        bookArray[0] = new Book("Java Programming", "Liang", 1320, 145.00);
        bookArray[1] = new Book("Horton Hears a Who!", "Dr. Suess", 72, 19.99);
        bookArray[2] = new Book("The Hobbit", "Tolkien", 320, 9.25);
        bookArray[3] = new Book("Born a Crime", "Noah", 304, 17.33);
        
        // use no-arg constructor to create books
        bookArray[4] = new Book();
        bookArray[5] = new Book();

        // foreach to print
        for (Book book: bookArray) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }
        System.out.println();

        
        finishArray(bookArray);  
        System.out.println("Books after completing library and 40% discount");

        for (Book book: bookArray) {
            System.out.println(book);
        }
        System.out.println("Most Expensive book after the discounts:\n" + reduceBooks(bookArray));
        System.out.println("Size of Library: " + bookArray.length + " books");


        
        
    }
         
    public static void finishArray(Book bookArray[]) {
        Book book;
        book = bookArray[4];
        book.setTitle("Dark Territory");
        book.setAuthor("Kaplan");
        book.setPages(352);
        book.setPrice(11.24);
        
        book = bookArray[5];
        book.setTitle("Born to Run");
        book.setAuthor("Springsteen");
        book.setPages(508);
        book.setPrice(12.17);
        
    }
           
             
    public static Book reduceBooks(Book bookArray[]) {
        Book most = bookArray[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
            Book book = bookArray[i];

            // see if this book is more expensive than current most
            if(book.getPrice() > most.getPrice()) {
                most = book;
            }

            // reduce price
            book.setPrice(book.getPrice() * 0.6);
        }

        return most; // return most expensive
    }
        
    

}
```

Here's my output which as you can see the discount does not apply to the second printing:

Title: Java Programming
Author: Liang
Pages: 1320
Price: 145.00

Title: Horton Hears a Who!
Author: Dr. Suess
Pages: 72
Price: 19.99

Title: The Hobbit
Author: Tolkien
Pages: 320
Price: 9.25

Title: Born a Crime
Author: Noah
Pages: 304
Price: 17.33

Title: null
Author: null
Pages: 0
Price: 0.00

Title: null
Author: null
Pages: 0
Price: 0.00

Books after completing library and 40% discount
Title: Java Programming
Author: Liang
Pages: 1320
Price: 145.00

Title: Horton Hears a Who!
Author: Dr. Suess
Pages: 72
Price: 19.99

Title: The Hobbit
Author: Tolkien
Pages: 320
Price: 9.25

Title: Born a Crime
Author: Noah
Pages: 304
Price: 17.33

Title: Dark Territory
Author: Kaplan
Pages: 352
Price: 11.24

Title: Born to Run
Author: Springsteen
Pages: 508
Price: 12.17

Most Expensive book after the discounts:
Title: Java Programming
Author: Liang
Pages: 1320
Price: 87.00

Size of Library: 6 books

Also, these are the instructions for the reduceBooks(), everything must be done in that method-

In reduceBooks():

this method returns a Book instance.
use a loop (any type) to reduce the price of every book in the array by 40%.
determine the most expensive book after the discounts and return this book to main.

Comment: You reduce the price in `reduceBooks`. You print the list before you call `reduceBooks`.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply discount before second print. Also, **do not forget to remove** reducing price code from `reduceBooks` or else you'll reduce price twice.

Here is an example how you can do it:

```
// first print

applyDiscount(bookArray);

// second print
```

```
public static void applyDiscount(Book bookArray[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
        Book book = bookArray[i];

        // reduce price
        book.setPrice(book.getPrice() * 0.6);
    }
}
```

Comment: The main point of 'reduceBooks' is reducing the price of the books, so it's silly to have 'reduceBooks' *not* reduce the price, but instead put that in a different method.  You'd end up with a method called 'reduceBooks' that *only* found the most expensive book.  You could usefully remove the functionality of 'find most expensive book' and put *that* in a separate function, leaving 'reduceBooks' with the job of reducing the price of the books.

Comment: @accessviolation or you can rename 'reduceBooks' to 'findMostExpensiveBook'

Comment: Sure, but it's perverse to remove from reduceBooks the part that is about 'reducing', create a different routine to do the reducing, and *then* rename the original because the name is now meaningless.

Comment: After a string "Most Expensive book after the discounts: " you expect a function that returns most expensive book, right?

Comment: Right. So before the 'print books' loop, call reduceBooks(), which no longer needs to return anything.  In the 'most expensive' print, call the new mostExpensive() routine.